# Would a proof-search for a contradiction halt in non-standard models of PA arithmetic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, turing-machines, incompleteness

I recently came across the following claim in [Eliezer Yudkowsky's post](https://www.alignmentforum.org/s/SqFbMbtxGybdS2gRs/p/SWn4rqdycu83ikfBa) about the limits of first-order logic

“ Suppose I build a Turing machine that looks for proofs of a contradiction from first-order Peano arithmetic. If PA's consistency isn't provable in PA, then by the Completeness Theorem there must exist nonstandard models of PA where this machine halts after finding a proof of a contradiction. So first-order logic doesn't tell me that this machine runs forever - maybe it has nonstandard halting time, i.e., it runs at all standard N, but halts at -2* somewhere along a disconnected chain.”

And I’m struggling with it. To me it seems to be false - it seems like the Completeness Theorem gets you a non-standard model in which PA’s consistency is *false*, but not one in which it is disprovable. Therefore there claim that a Turing machine conducting a *proof search* would halt in this model seems to not follow? I’m quite confused by some of the wording though so perhaps I’ve misunderstood. Clarity would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Doesn't "PA's consistency is false" mean exactly the same thing as "a Turing machine hunting for proofs of 0=1 from PA will find one"?

Comment: Yeah I get that sure - reflecting on it a bit I think my confusion was the wording of the sentence “  there must exist nonstandard models of PA where this machine halts after finding a proof of a contradiction”. I read this as the author claiming that the behaviour of the purely syntactic proof search somehow depended on a semantic choice of model (which was kind of my issue with it). But in retrospect they’re just making the pretty standard claim that PA can’t prove its consistency

Comment: But it does... the "purely syntactic proof search" looks different in different models, sometimes terminating with a proof of inconsistency, sometimes not. (But any search that does yield inconsistency will necessarily take a nonstandard number of steps to get there or use nonstandard PA axioms.)

Comment: It looks different from the perspective of the model depending yes but my point was it obviously doesn’t from the perspective of standing outside PA which is what I thought the author was claiming. I didn’t read them as making claims about what the model said about the proof search - from that perspective I agree it’s straightforward. Just terrible reading comprehension on my part I guess